# How to display decimals on android studio

Tags: android-studio, variables, double

Hello I have a problem between the double and int

my code "works" when I put the variables in int but I do not have the numbers after the decimal point as soon as I put in duplicate it puts the result to me at 0 and I do not see why

MyCartAdpter

```
public class MyCartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCartAdapter.ViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<MyCartModel> list;
double totalAmount =0;
 ...
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

 ...
  holder.totalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getTotalPrice()));

    //total amount pass to cart activity
    totalAmount = (totalAmount + list.get(position).getTotalPrice());
    Intent intent = new Intent("MyTotalAmount");
intent.putExtra("totalAmount",totalAmount);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

MyCartModel

```
           public class MyCartModel {

            ...
            double totalPrice;
           ...
           }
           public MyCartModel(..., double totalPrice, ...) {
           ...
           this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
           ...
            }
           public double getTotalPrice() {
            return totalPrice;
            }

             public void setTotalPrice(double totalPrice) {
             this.totalPrice = totalPrice;
              }
```

and my CartActivity

```
       public BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        double totalBill = intent.getIntExtra("totalAmount",0);
        overAllAmount.setText("Montant Total :"+totalBill+"€");
    }
};
```

thank you for your help because for 24 hours I have been looking

Comment: Hi! i don't do any android studio, was curious so i opened that, i am probably wrong but getIntExtra return int or double? maybe its here that you lose your cents

Comment: hello then the int returns me an integer to have the decimal it is necessary to pass in double if I remain on the int I have the number the in third for example 101 instead of 101.6 and if I pass it in double the calculate it does not happen do more and show me 0.0

Answer (score 0):

overAllAmount.setText(String.format("%.2f",totalBill));

Could also put the textviews input type to numberdecimal

android:inputType="numberDecimal"

Happy coding